# regex works in online tool but doesn't agree with NSRegularExpression

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

```swift
do {
    // initialization failed, looks like I can not use "\\" here
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(?<!\\)\n")

    let string = """
    aaabbb
    zzz
    """
    
    // expect "aaabbb\nzzz"
    print(regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count), withTemplate: "\\n"))
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Here I want to replace "\n" in my string with "\\n", but failed at the very beginning, the error message is

```
// NSRegularExpression did not recognize the pattern correctly.
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “(?<!\)
” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue=(?<!\)
}
```

The regex has been tested in [regular expression 101](https://regex101.com), so it is right, just doesn't work in Swift for some reason.

How can I do this?

Comment: in Swift, `\\` (double back slash) in a String is for "having a `\`, as you see in the error, you have `(?<!\)`, but it means then that you are escaping the closing `)`, so you have a missing closing `)`. I'd say that you should write then `"(?<!\\\\)\n"`?

Comment: @Larme This does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on Larme's comment:

> in Swift, `\` (double back slash) in a String is for "having a ``, as you see in the error, you have `(?<!\)`, but it means then that you are escaping the closing `)`, so you have a missing closing `)`. I'd say that you should write then `"(?<!\\\\)\n"`?

I finally figured out what's going on and how to fix it.

The problem is **backslash**.

In Swift, a backslash inside double quotation mark would be treated as **escape sequence**, like this

```swift
// won't compile
// error: Invalid escape sequence in literal
let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(?<!\)\n")
```

If we add another backslash, is it work?

No, cause these 2 backslashes would be treated as a single **escape character** for the upcoming closing ).

```swift
// compile but get a runtime error
let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(?<!\\)\n")
```

Hence the runtime error

```bash
NSRegularExpression did not recognize the pattern correctly.
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “(?<!\)
” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue=(?<!\)
```

To show that what we need is a literal backslash, we actually need 4 backslashes

```swift
let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "(?<!\\\\)\n")
```

The first two backslashes represent an escape character and the last two represent one literal backslash.

These seem very troublesome.

#### Better Approach

Fortunately, starting with Swift 5, we can use a pair of # to do this

```swift
// works like in online tool
let regex = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: #"(?<!\\)\n"#)
```

#### Another thing

It’s worth noticing that the initialization of regular expression isn’t the only thing that requires special handling

```swift
// withTemplate
print(regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count), withTemplate: #"\\n"#))

// As a comparison, this is OK
print(string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\N"))
```